# Running gunicorn on ubuntu based image using docker-compose

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have image using ubuntu as a base image which runs gunicorn with my flask app on it and it runs fine when using just docker. This is my image.

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -yqq python2.7 python-pip python-dev wget vim gunicorn python-virtualenv supervisor
RUN pip install gunicorn

#KONFIGURACJA QGIS 
RUN echo "deb http://qgis.org/debian-ltr trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-ltr trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN wget -O - http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2016.gpg.key | gpg --import && gpg --fingerprint 073D307A618E5811 && gpg --export --armor 073D307A618E5811 | apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq \
    libpq-dev python-dev qgis2.14.7 python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass python-pip

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod +x ./run.py
RUN chmod +x ./start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```

This commands work properly but this image dont have access to services speficied in docker composer:

```
docker build -t habibi07/web
docker run habibi07/web
```

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  restart: always
  image: habibi07/web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - mongodb:mongodb
    - redis:redis
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/app/static
    - /root/projekty:/usr/src/app/app/static/projekty
  volumes_from:
    - data
  env_file: .env
nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
 volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web
```

As i said it runs fine when using docker, the problem shows up when i try to use it in docker compose file. Web service logs shows this error.

> ./start.sh: line 2: gunicorn: command not found

And this is endpoint.

```
#!/bin/bash
gunicorn -w 8 -b :8000 app.main:app
```

I have totaly no idea why it is not working. Gunicorn is certainly, both using pip and apt. I've tried to set PATH env but it didn't work too. I know that i should run gunicorn on python based image but i can't because i need access to qgis libraries which runs on ubuntu base image. Maybe docker compose has it's own context from where gunicorn is not available ?

Comment: Could you also include the command that works for starting your service?

Comment: I've added command that works. I can build and run image but i can't use it in docker compose